# HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes vs HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Tags: registry

In Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/interface-key), I found the following paragraph

> The **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes** key corresponds to the **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT** key, which was retained for compatibility with earlier versions of COM.

Now, I am not sure which key the *which* in that paragraph refers to: the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes or the HKCU key.

I'd appreciate if someone could clarify.

Comment: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` (**HKCR**) is exact copy of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes`. Another is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` (**HKCU**) although  there is  (different) `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` (abbrev. `HKCR`, not to be confused with `HKC`**`U`**, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`) is a **merged** view of the `...\Software\Classes` sub hierarchies in HKLM *and* HKCU.

This is actually documented, although it is not linked from the [COM docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/interface-key) you refer to:

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/hkey-classes-root-key):

> Class registration and file name extension information is stored under
>   both the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` keys. The
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` key contains default settings that
>   can apply to all users on the local computer. The
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` key contains settings that apply
>   only to the interactive user. The `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key provides a
>   **view of the registry that merges the information from these two**
>   sources. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` *also* provides this merged view for
>   applications designed for previous versions of Windows.

They even go into the [details of this merge mess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/merged-view-of-hkey-classes-root), but if you need any specific behavior from the merged view, you would be well advised to verify it, because the details are rather messy in my opinon:

- For reading, essentially most of the stuff is merged, that is you will see both keys and both values from overlapping keys.
- When you have the same *value* in both, you will most likely see the one from HKCU, not from HKLM.
- When you have the same/overlapping key in both, you will see its merged values and subkeys. (Or so I think.) (At least on Win7.)
- When you write via HKCR, it will depend on whether you are admin or not. And whether you run under UAC or not. *Do try not to write via HKCR*, it will make your life easier.

  - Specifically, I'm referring to [this gem](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/256986/windows-registry-information-for-advanced-users) (which is what you can actually observe):

    > If you **write keys** to a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, the system stores 
    >   the information under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE**\Software\Classes.
    >
    > If you **write values** to a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, and the key 
    >   already exists under **HKEY_CURRENT_USER**\Software\Classes, the system 
    >   will store the information there instead of under 
    >   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes.